# Conditional formatting - cells in a range that having matching values from another range

Tags: google-sheets

I'm in a few Discord servers that let users hold auctions of in-game items to be exchanged for an unofficial in-game currency.  Since some users will bid but fail to follow through on the trade, I have a way of marking that user (for my own personal records) as a bad trader.  What I'm trying to do is set up conditional formatting on the row of the auction information to highlight in a red color if the ID of the user (long ID not their tag) matches someone on that list.  I have conditional formatting set up to highlight the rows for other reasons and those work great.

Using an `arrayFormula()` in column L, I've included this code:

`LOOKUP(D2:D,Discord!F2:F)`

It lists either N/A or the Discord ID number of the user if there's a match.  I then hide that column and have the conditional formatting formula as `"=$D2:$D=$L2:$L"` to find matches.

What I would like to do is to accomplish the same result but without using a dedicated column to do it.  Simply put, conditional formatting that will return true when a value from one row in the range matches a value from any row in another range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this custom formula:

`=countif(INDIRECT("Discord!$F2:$F"),$D1)>0`

See it working in this example sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1izTh57D58QiG_SOx-IyQW5SLwtAb0FqvDopeArgRnog/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Beautiful.  Just gave it a try and does exactly what I'm looking for, and is much MUCH less complicated than what I was using.  Thank you!